# Open source search written in Go

Tags: search, full-text-search, go

Does anyone know of any open source search projects written in Go?

I want to implement a simple site search for my site and am looking for a web crawler, but more specifically, a search algorithm written in Go.

Any ideas, projects, or suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the web crawler part, there`s gocrawl: https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/gocrawl

Disclaimer: I'm the author.

Comment: Thank you for the disclaimer! How good does it work? What does it / can it do?

Comment: Looks like both of you answered half of my question at the same time. I don't know who to give the tick-mark too...

Comment: It's a pretty generic crawler, the basic features are extensibility, good web citizen (respect of robots.txt rules, delays), it runs a single goroutine per host, so multiple hosts can be crawled in parallel. The repo is reasonably well documented in the readme, and feel free to open an issue or drop me an email if you have specific issues with the library.

Comment: Okay, will do! Thank you for this. Now I just have to find or write a search algorithm to search against what I crawl.

Comment: Can I use your crawler to parse XML and / or PDFs ?

Comment: It's more focused towards HTML, it won't *parse* other types per se, but you will get the request's body, and then you can do whatever you have to do with it (it *will* parse HTML bodies, though, and provide you with a goquery document - think jquery in Go - for those requests).

Comment: Ah, thank you. I found a way to parse XML in Go.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the suffixarray implementation in Go's standard library: http://golang.org/pkg/index/suffixarray/

Take a look at godoc how it can be used.